# Passing state between sibling components React Router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I want to pass state between various sibling components: `Dashboard` and all routes which contain `/overall`.  Thea idea is that I can click a button on any of the pages which contain `/overall` in the URL  and it gets the corresponding value and moves that value to the dashboard. I've been doing some reading around this subject however I'm struggling to understand which is the best implementation for my purpose.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Router from "./components/Router";
import registerServiceWorker from "./registerServiceWorker";
import "./css/style.css";
render(<Router />, document.getElementById("main"));
registerServiceWorker();
```

Router.js

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import NameSelector from "./NameSelector";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import OverallGoals from "./OverallGoals";
import OverallShots from "./OverallShots";
import OverallPossession from "./OverallPossession";
import OverallResults from "./OverallResults";
import OverallFormations from "./OverallFormations";
const Router = () => (
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={NameSelector} />
      <Route exact path="/:gamerId/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
      <Route exact path="/:gamerId/overall/goals" component={OverallGoals} />
      <Route exact path="/:gamerId/overall/shots" component={OverallShots} />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/:gamerId/overall/results"
        component={OverallResults}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/:gamerId/overall/possession"
        component={OverallPossession}
      />
      <Route
        exact
        path="/:gamerId/overall/formations"
        component={OverallFormations}
      />
      <Route component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  </BrowserRouter>
);

export default Router;
```

From my understanding, passing state through the `Route` wouldn't work as `Route` doesn't actually render anything. I need a parent component to hold state for both siblings however it doesn't make sense to make a component solely for managing state between the two components (or would it?).

What's the best practice for this and how would it fit into my codebase?

Also, I want to avoid Redux for now, as I will appreciate the technology more when I implement this solution in pure React.

Fairly new to React, I understand this code could be slightly more efficient.

EDIT: `NameSelector` is a component which holds an input field which once submitted `push()`es to a URL containing the input

Regards,
James.

Answer (score 1):

> I need a parent component to hold state for both siblings however it doesn't make sense to make a component solely for managing state between the two components (or would it?).

It does!

Pretty much, short of using Redux or the [React Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), you are going to need a common parent component that holds, shares, and manages updates to the state that you'd like your two sibling components to share.

If your component-tree is simple and short, and the sibling components are in close proximity (i.e. you don't need to pass the state up-and-down multiple tiers), then this configuration makes a lot of sense. Have a parent component that manages state, render the two siblings underneath it.

If the tree structure is (or will become) complex, with components and subcomponents separated from each other across multiple tiers, then start thinking about and investing in a Redux store.

Comment: Just updated the question. It's actually various sibling components that need to be tracked, not just two. You might think that the Dashboard should be the parent component however they are different entities in the application (as in, ```overall``` isn't a sub-directory of ```dashboard```). I think I'm just getting hung up on how the ```Router``` file would conditionally render either  the ```Dashboard``` or the ```overall``` pages, as they would be both enclosed in the parent component